# Google Chrome screen pixelated

Tags: catalina, google-chrome

I have a brand new MacBook Pro (16" 2019 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7) and this keeps happening in Google Chrome. I have restarted several times and it eventually goes back to this. Just doing a hard close on Chrome doesn't work.

I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.7 and Google Chrome (86.0.4240.193).

So far, it's only Google Chrome that this happens to. Anyone have any debugging tips?

[image]

Comment: Don't have refs to hand, but that's at least the third time in the past week I've seen that complaint.

Comment: RE: "new Mac Book Pro" , "I'm on the latest Chrome" -- Please provide the actual specifications and not "_latest_". Which model **MacBook Pro**, what versions of **macOS** and  **Google Chrome**?

Comment: @user3439894 you betcha! Updated with specs.

Comment: @Tetsujin I haven't even had this Mac a week yet. I tried googling it, but I don't know the right terms so I couldn't find anything. Someone said it was an external monitor issue, but I don't think so since it happens on any monitor.

Comment: As it seems to have sprung from nowhere in just the past week, for several people, I'm going to point at Chrome, not the Mac. But I have absolutely nothing but conjecture to base that on.

Comment: Which model **MacBook Pro**?

Comment: @Tetsujin there was an update just this morning but after installing it, it really didn't do anything. Hopefully they will have another fix soon.

Comment: @user3439894 16 in 2019 Processor 2 Ghz 6-Core intel Core i7.

Comment: I'm using a **MacBook Pro** (16" 2019 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9) and **Google Chrome** 86.0.4240.183 and have not experienced this issue. I have now updated to **Google Chrome** 86.0.4240.193 and will see if the issue you've described is reproducible on my system too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling hardware acceleration: `chrome://settings/?search=hardware`

[image]

I had exactly same issue: [Strange video glitch in Chrome browser](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/406479/22752) and [@jaume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/32815/jaume) suggested that. Maybe it will help?

Comment: I was gonna say that it happened the day or so after in Microsoft Teams but it was when I had Chrome open too. After reading the comments, sounds like Chrome screws with the OS a little bit so this might be it. I'll try that and see. THANKS!!