# Strange video glitch in Chrome browser

Tags: catalina, google-chrome, graphics

- macOS Catalina
- Version 10.15.7
- MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)

#### 18s video on YouTube: https://youtu.be/mk-jj-MZ-CM

Tiny preview below:

[image]

I like art but this is annoying.

Last time restarting machine resolved the issue but it's popping up again :(

Comment: This is at least the 4th of these in the past week [can't trace the others right now] - the common factor is always Chrome.

Comment: @Tetsujin I found one of the related posts: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406077/google-chrome-screen-pixelated

Comment: Which is your version of Chrome? Is it by any chance 86.0.4240.193? Have you enabled hardware acceleration (Settings > Advanced > Enable Hardware Acceleration)?

Comment: @jaume `Version 86.0.4240.193 (Official Build) (x86_64)` yeah, it was enabled, now disabling.

Comment: Thanks, others have reported similar problems, there seems to be an issue with version 86.0.4240.193 that affects certain Mac configurations. Could you post your Mac model? It may help others troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: @jaume `MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)`

Comment: It is pretty common nowadays, something about Chrome. Wait for chrome to solve, even there is a solution by doing something waiting for google would be better for your regular usage.